# Limit of probability of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, uniform-distribution

Let $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables each following a uniform distribution $U(0, 1).$ How do I find $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_n\le 3n/4)$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(U_1+\cdots+U_n) = \frac n2. \\[8pt]
& \operatorname{sd}(U_1+\cdots+U_n) = \text{constant} \times \sqrt n. \\
& \quad\text{(where “constant” means not changing as $n$ changes).}
\end{align}
Ask yourself how many standard deviations above the mean $3n/4$ is, and what Chebyshev's inequality says about the probability of being that many standard deviations above the mean.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a consequence of the law of large numbers after a suitable rewriting of your expression.